# Derivation of conservation of mass equation using the method of contradiction. Proof verification.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

*Conservation of mass equation derivation:-*

Suppose $\int _0^T\int _{x_1}^{x_2}\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t{,}x\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t{,}x\right)v\left(t{,}x\right)\right)\right\}dxdt=0$ for all $ (t,x)\in [0,T]\times[x_1,x_2]$ ( Where $[0,T]\subseteq[0,\infty)$ and $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq[0,\infty)$). Then $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t{,}x\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t{,}x\right)v\left(t{,}x\right)\right)=0, \forall (t,x)\in [0,\infty)\times[0,\infty).$

**My attempt:-**
Assume there exists a point $(t_0,x_0)\in [0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$ such that

$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t_0{,}x_0\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t_0{,}x_0\right)v\left(t_0{,}x_0\right)\right)\neq0.$

By assuming $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t{,}x\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t{,}x\right)v\left(t{,}x\right)\right)$ continuous(Since the phenomenon of nature and quantities are smooth). We can take a neighbourhood  of $(t_0,x_0)\in (t_1,t_2)\times (x'_1,x'_2)$ such that $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t_0{,}x_0\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t_0{,}x_0\right)v\left(t_0{,}x_0\right)\right)\neq0$ in $(t_1,t_2)\times (x'_1,x'_2)$.
Without Loss of genrality, assume  $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t_0{,}x_0\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t_0{,}x_0\right)v\left(t_0{,}x_0\right)\right)>0.$ That means $\int _{t_1}^{t_2}\int _{x'_1}^{x'_2}\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\rho \left(t{,}x\right)+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\rho \left(t{,}x\right)v\left(t{,}x\right)\right)\right\}dxdt>0.$ Which is a contradiction to our assumption. Hence proved. Is my proof coorect?

Comment: That should be $\partial_x$ on the $\rho v$ term, right?

Comment: While the given information involves integration between two arbitrary values of $x$, for $t$ only one of the ends is arbitrary. The other is $0$. Your argument relies on integrating time between two arbitrary values. You need to justify that. I would also say that nature *can always be modelled by smooth functions*. This is not because nature is itself smooth, but rather the measured quantities are only defined up to a certain level of accuracy. But that is a philosophical point, not a problem in your argument.

Comment: Thank you@eyeballfrog